# Selenium on Jenkins is skipping all the tests

Tags: selenium, jenkins, gradle

- Java: 8
- Selenium: 3.14
- Browser: Firefox 62.0.2
- Geckodriver: v0.22.0

The Selenium execution of my project on Jenkins is skipping all tests:
[Jenkins log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qV3xH.png)

This is the dependencies of selenium on my build.gradle file:

```
['org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:3.14.0'],
['org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-server:3.14.0'],
['org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-api:3.14.0'],
['org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-support:3.14.0'],
['org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-remote-driver:3.14.0'],
['org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-firefox-driver:3.14.0'],
['org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-chrome-driver:3.14.0']
```

And here is where I set the geckodriver path. I'm using only firefox:

```
@Before
public void openResources() {

    if( webDriver == null ){
        String geckodriver = seleniumProperties.getString("selenium.caminhoGeckodriver");

        try {
            String browser = seleniumProperties.getString("selenium.browser");

            if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(browser) && browser.toLowerCase().equals("chrome")) {
                String path = seleniumProperties.getString("selenium.browser.path");
                System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", path);
                webDriver = new ChromeDriver();
            } else {
                System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", geckodriver);
                webDriver = new FirefoxDriver();
            }
        } catch (MissingResourceException e) {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", geckodriver);
            webDriver = new FirefoxDriver();
        }
    }

    webDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    webDriver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    webDriver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    efetuarLogin();
}
```

The geckodriver path is set right on my seleniumProperties. The firefox version installed on the environment is 62.0.2.

On Eclipse, the tests are not skipped.

UPDATE:
That's the piece of code where is defined the task runSelenium (check the image with the Jenkins log that I posted):

```
task runSelenium(type: Test) {
    include( '**/myProjectSuiteSelenium.class')
    maxHeapSize = "1524m"
    jvmArgs "-XX:MaxPermSize=512m", "-XX:-UseSplitVerifier"
}

test.finalizedBy runSelenium
```

Comment: What happens when you run Gradle manually?

Comment: When I run gradle manually, the tests are executed. By the way, the version of gradle is 2.2.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was the problem.

The problem was that the Jenkins wasn't logging the real error. My seleniumProperties was referencing the wrong file with the selenium properties. So it wasn't getting the right geckodriver file.

Once I change to the right file, the tests were not skipped anymore.

Answer (score 0):

```
include( '**/myProjectSuiteSelenium.class')
```

Remove this include and replace it with something that matches your actual tests.

I see "selenium.*" in the Jenkins logs.